# Unable to install printer driver for HP1606DN printer on Big Sur

Tags: printing, driver

I have tried to configure the HP1606DN printer via IP address, direct driver download, `EasySetup`, and  `HP Smart`: none have worked.

For newer printers my preference for installation is to connect via IP address and then hopefully the printer will download the drivers properly.  For the HP1606DN I believe that were the case in the past: but it is not working now because only `Generic PostScript` or an incompatible HP printer type are  available.

So I have downloaded the HP driver from https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-pro-p1606-printer-series/4110408/model/4110409

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I installed `EasySetup 2` and then connected by USB (I'd prefer to do ethernet but apparently we need a physical connection ??)  It asks me to install yet *another* program `HP Smart`. This is obviously troubling - since too many programs mean too many chances for the programs to fail or get confused.

Then the `HP Smart` setup program *still* does not recognize the printer - it hangs here:

[image]

And it can't find the (correctly attached) USB

[image]

Note that I had previously tried using drivers directly: `HPPrinterDrivers5.1.dmg`

> This volume does not meet the requirements for this update

I am at a loss to how to get this (relatively recent!) printer to work with _macOS Big Sur. Has anyone succeeded?

[image]

Comment: That printer doesn't speak Postscript, per its specifications page, it's a host-based printer.  So it's stupid.  You need software on the computer side to render the pages.

Comment: Have you try : 1) Reset Mac Printing System :  https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reset-mac-printing-system-solve-a-problem-mh14001/mac 2) reboot the Mac, plug the printer then run HP Easy Star program?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to install that exact printer in a few Macs running Big Sur. Although, it's definitely giving me more problems when printing than when I was running previous MacOS versions.

I know you said you tried to install the HP Drivers 5.1 with the error you mentioned, but I would try to download the installer from: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1888?locale=en_US, the filename will be a bit different from the one you mentioned (`HewlettPackardPrinterDrivers.dmg`). I've installed that driver in multiple Big Sur computers, so I would suggest to try again.

Try to reset the Mac Printing System as suggested in a comment, and install the driver again.